# Invalid Binary in itunesconnect for phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova, itunes

I have created ios app in phonegap, when I uploaded it to itunes, it shows "Invalid Binary" in "Prerelease" section of app. I got a mail from apple stating that "Missing 64-bit support". So I set architectures as "armv64, armv7, armv7s" and build active architecture to "No". Then I again uploaded the binary with incremented version, but again it shows "Invalid Binary". Then I found on google, phonegap version should be upgraded to "3.5" for 64 bit support. So I upgraded the cordova lib to 3.5 and uploaded the app again. But still it is showing "Invalid Binary".

I downloaded the cordova 3.5 project from github and removed previous cordova build from my iOS project and added the latest build. Is it the right process for upgrading the lib or do I need to do some other process?

Please help to identify the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's arm64, not armv64. 
Second, to update the app you have to update the project too, not just the cordova lib

So, first you update the cordova lib with this command:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

then you go to your project and update it

```
cd your_project_folder
cordova platform update ios
```

Note that your app must be on a cordova 3.X.X version to update like this